# if statement check active class when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to make an if statement in JS that when one of the top 3 buttons changes, it checks which of the bottom 2 has the "active" class, and visa versa.

So when I click 30g it will check if option a or option b is active, and then change the price accordingly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm kind of a noob.

The problem is there are 2 rows of buttons (one to select the weight, and one to select option a or b). I know how it would work, I just don't know the syntax, this is what I want to happen but it's not coded right.

```
//this is shitty code of what I mean, but I don't know how to code in JS
 if(button30g.isclicked && buttonOptionA.ContainsClass.Active) 
    { Price=1.00; } 
    else if(button30g.isClicked && buttonOptionB.ContainsClass.Active) 
    { Price=2.00; } 
    if(button70g.isclicked && buttonOptionA.ContainsClass.Active) 
    { Price=3.50; } 
    else if(button70g.isClicked && buttonOptionB.ContainsClass.Active) 
    { Price=4.00; } 
    if(button70g.isclicked && buttonOptionA.ContainsClass.Active) 
    { Price=3.50; } 
    else if(button70g.isClicked && buttonOptionB.ContainsClass.Active) 
    { Price=4.00; }


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
ul.nav a{
border: 2px solid #E1E8EE;
border-radius: 6px;
padding: 13px 20px;
font-size: 14px;
color: #5E6977;
background-color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
transition: all .5s;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.activeBtn { color:grey; font-weight:1000; border: 2px solid grey; border-radius: 6px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="nav">
<li id="30" data-price="bird" onclick="myFunction()"  class="activeBtn"><a>30g</a></li>
<li id="70" onclick="myFunction()"><a>70g</a></li>
<li id="90" onclick="myFunction()"><a>90g</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav">
<li id="no" class="activeBtn"><a>option a</a></li>
<li id="yes"><a>option b</a></li>
</ul>
<br>
<div class="product-price">
<span id="price">148$</span>
</div>
</body>
<footer>
<script>
$(function() {
$( 'ul.nav li' ).on( 'click', function() {
$( this ).parent().find( 'li.activeBtn' ).removeClass( 'activeBtn' );
$( this ).addClass( 'activeBtn' );
});
});
</script>
<script>
function myFunction() {
const element = document.getElementById("30");
const element2 = document.getElementById("no");
const pricetag = document.getElementById("price");
if(((element.classList.contains("activeBtn"))==true)&&((element2.classList.contains("activeBtn"))==true))
{
pricetag.innerHTML = €1,00;
}
</script>
</footer>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The work that you want I have done it separately so check this out. This code works according to the option "yes" or "no" and shows the price.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
    .radioStyle{
        border-color: blue;
        border-width: thin;
        border-style: solid;
        width: 50%;
        
    }
    
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div><input  type="radio" name="grams" value="30" id = "30" onclick="myFunction()"> 30g</div>
    
    <div><input type="radio" name="grams" value="70" id = "70" onclick="myFunction()"> 70g</div>
    
    <div><input type="radio" name="grams" value="90" id = "90" onclick="myFunction()"> 90g </div>
    
    
    <hr>
    
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="yes" id ="yes" checked onclick="myFunction()"> yes<br>
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="no" id = "no" onclick="myFunction()"> no<br>
    <br>
    <span id = "sp">
      0$
    </span>
  
   

</body>
<footer>
    <script>
        
        function setBorder(){
           var siblings = document.querySelectorAll('input[name = "grams"]');
            siblings.forEach(element => element.parentElement.className="");
             var grams = document.querySelector('input[name = "grams"]:checked');
            grams.parentElement.className = "radioStyle";
            console.log(siblings);
             console.log(grams);
        }
        
        
    function myFunction(){
        setBorder();
        var grams = document.querySelector('input[name = "grams"]:checked').value;
        var option =   document.querySelector('input[name = "option"]:checked').value;
       
        var rate = 0;
        if (option == "yes"){
            if (grams == "30")
                rate = 1.5;
            else if (grams == "70")
                rate = 2.5;
            else if (grams == "90")
                rate = 3.5;
        }
        else if (option == "no"){
            if (grams == "30")
                rate = 2;
            else if (grams == "70")
                rate = 3;
            else if (grams == "90")
                rate = 4;
        }
                                
        document.getElementById("sp").innerHTML = rate*grams+"$";
      
 }
    </script>
</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: uhm yeah thx, but when u change the yes and no buttons,the price doesn't change

Comment: Now it updates the price when YES or NO is changed. Let me know if it is working fine now. Don't forget to mark it as right answer if it helped 